# How to define constants with PECL hidef?

Tags: php

I've recently convinced the team that we could upgrade from php5.4 to 5.5 -- but, unfortunately, it seems I overlooked that php-apc is no longer supported in php 5.5 -- which is fine and dandy, but we could use a replacement for apc_define_constants()

Thus, I've heard about the wonders of hidef -- but, I cannot seem to find any documentation for it, anywhere -- I got it installed, after a bit of kajiggering, but I'm not sure what to do next...

How could I go about unwrapping the various functions included in the pecl hidef package ?

Or, at the very least, how can I use it to define constants?

Comment: Have you looked at APCu? It is a fork of APC doing only the userland caching to sit next to opcache. I haven't checked whether it has the apc_define_cosntants() feature. http://pecl.php.net/apcu

Comment: I did, and I could not find anything that resembled apc_define_constants -- but then again, I didn't look too hard... I was honestly thinking about going to xcache, now - but I'll have to do some research, first.

Comment: As said I haven't checked that, you might report it as a bug to APCu, as it might be an oversight on their side while throwing out code. I answered about hidef below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very small piece of documentation in the INSTALL file of the binary distribution [here.](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/hidef/trunk/INSTALL?revision=231339&view=markup)

For using hidef you first have to define a configuration directory. Default is /etc/php/hidef, but you can (and should, since /etc/php/ probably doesn't exist) define a directory in your ini as so:

```
hidef.ini_path=/etc/php5/hidef/
```

Also, don't forget to make sure the extension is enabled in the .ini, also:

```
extension=hidef.so
```

On PHP startup it will scan all files in there and read them in. One might do for instance

```
$ echo "int ANSWER = 42;" > /etc/php/hidef/sample.ini
```

on command line and then test using

```
$ php -r 'echo ANSWER;'
```

If you try this in a web server you might have to restart it after changing the configuration.

Comment: Ah, good catch --- I created the directory and added the `hidef.ini_path=/etc/php/hidef/` to my php.ini -- restarted fpm - it works! 
I'll edit your answer to include those details and accept it momentarily.